# AWS Scalable Architecture Design

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services

I am currently implementing my first web app utilizing AWS infrastructure and learning the basics.  I've run into a design issue so came up with the following scenario to illustrate my problem:

Suppose I were making a web app that saves / prints a website as pdf and stores it on S3.  The front end has a single form.  A user would type in a url for the site they want to save to pdf and click submit.  The app should print the page at the given url to pdf and present the file to the user.

To make the app scalable I imagined clicking submit will send an SQS message to a queue with the url to process.  A fleet of workers could then consume from this queue, create the pdfs & store them in S3, then store the S3 key / path to SimpleDB.  The trouble I am having is how does a worker then notify the web app that processing is complete?

Example Design:
[image: Example Design]

I imagine the Web App could continually poll SimpleDB until an entry for the S3 key appears however this solution seems a bit clumsy.  I feel this is a pattern / problem must commonly be encountered.  Could anyone provide a common way to address this?

Additionally any recommended resources for common design patterns in the cloud would be greatly beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using something like WebSockets, I don't see this being an issue. When the user makes a request, the web application would poll SimpleDB (like you mentioned) to check if the processing was complete (or if there was an error). With something like WebSockets, then you could have another queue that the web application would subscribe to to be notified when processing was complete, to then notify the browser that it was complete.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Greg. I am not sure having the front end subscribing to a queue makes sense as there could be multiple web app instances running behind the ELB. However having them all subscribe to an SNS topic may make sense. I have very little experience programming on the front end, however, and was unsure how I would make the page refresh upon receipt of an SNS notification. Each web app would have to check some sort of session id upon receipt of an SNS message and verify whether or not that it relates to a session currently active on that machine. Beyond that I am a bit stuck :P

Comment: I suppose polling SimpleDB repeatedly isn't _that_ bad, however I thought there may be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Once the user's browser makes the request to start processing, you return a response right away. Unless you are holding the connection open to the browser, the user will have to poll the web server to check if the processing has completed. A request to SimpleDB is pretty cheap (compared to what you would have to do to support the instant page refresh with WebSockets or something similar). You can use an AJAX request in the background to poll for the result and then update the page when processing has completed.

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated, you've basically solved all your problems except for the front-end, which would need to poll our backend API to see if the media was ready. At my company, we do what you said above, rendering webpage screenshots, but also jpg snapshots of PDFs, office documents, and processing encoding video and audio.

We use ajax for updates, and have them set so they will ping a few times a second then gradually fallback to once a second and once every few seconds to not put too much of a strain on our servers. The other option, as the other answer mentioned, would be using websockets, which is a persisten connection to the server that you can "push" and "pull" data from. Most everyone uses the ajax polling approach though. With old technologies like Apache, this could be a big deal for thousands of connections, but with things like Nginx, Node, and intermediate caching it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an object (like a marker) in S3 and then poll S3 instead of simple DB. This way you can avoid put stress on your SimpleDB, and your polling performance will me more stable.

You could do this approach polling from you web app instance or even polling from the ajax layer. (though the latter is not the best choice as any error in those calls will not be logged in your server)